# SUM and SUM in SQL request in the same table

Tags: sql

This is a general SQL question, but I use Firebird.

I have this table (simplified):

```
id  amount  type  idtype
--------------------
1    10      in1   0
2    15      in2   0
3    5       out1  1
4    4       out2  1
5    5       out3  2
```

idtype column "shows" the id of incoming part and to add: i can't use "type" column in my ask form, 'cause type is diffrent every time. 
idtype for incoming has '0' and that means 'incoming part'

So, I'd like to have the result:

```
id   in      out  
--------------------
1    10      9    
2    15      5
```

I've tried in this way:

```
select
  id,
  amount,
   (
    select
      SUM (amount) as together
    from
      mytable
    where
      idtype  0
    group by
      id
   ) as "out"
from
  mytable
where
  idtype = 0
```

but this doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `id` field instead of `idtype` in the condition, and you are not matching the records that you want to sum to anything.

```
select
  id,
  amount,
   (
    select
      SUM (amount) as together
    from
      mytable
    where
      idtype = t.id
   ) as "out"
from
  mytable t
where
  idtype = 0
```

You can also write it as a join:

```
select
  id,
  amount,
  sum(t2.amount) as "out"
from
  mytable t
  innerjoin mytable t2 on t2.idtype = t.id
group by
  t.id, t.amount
where
  idtype = 0
```